# How to operate two variables with one factor in R

Tags: r, group-by, r-factor

I was trying to do this: (the following dataframe is just to show the idea)

```
      a     b     c

[1,]  1     1     2

[2,]  1     3     5

[3,]  2     2     4

[4,]  2     1     5
```

in which 'a' is the factor that groups 'b' and 'c' into two categories. I want to get the weighted mean of a (b as the weight, or actually, b/Sum(b) as the weight). I couldn't find a function that operates more than one variables with the same factor.

In this example, i want to get two means:

group a=1: (1*2+3*5)/(2+5)=17/7

group a=2: (2*4+1*5)/(4+5)=13/9

I'm new to R so this is really hard for me to handle. Hope you guys could spare a few seconds to comment. Thanks very much!

Comment: Pick your favorite answer from the [Mean by Group R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061), and use `weighted.mean` instead of `mean`.

Comment: Thank you! Just saw the comment, I will try to understand those codes! ( I think it’s because I searched for sth. else instead of “mean” in the beginning that I didn’t see the page you pasted.

Comment: The term *"operate two variables with one factor"* doesn't make sense to me. I think you meant *"group_by/split on levels of a factor"*. Tagged [tag:group-by]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the `matrix` (based on the structure showed) to `data.frame`, grouped by 'a', `summarise` by taking the `sum` of the product of 'b', 'c', divided by the `sum` of 'c'

```
library(dplyr)
m1 %>%
   as.data.frame %>% # if it is a matrix
   group_by(a) %>%
   summarise(new = sum(b*c)/sum(c))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#       a   new
#   <int> <dbl>
#1     1  2.43
#2     2  1.44
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L), .Dim = c(4L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I ran the code and it does give a similar output (A tibble: 109 x 2 in my case). However the 'new' column are all same values. I don't know where i did  wrong...if 'local' is already a dataframe, can i do this:`local%>%group_by(local$bond)%>%summarize(new=crossprod(local$gross,local$latestytm)/sum(local$gross))`?   now  it works ! Thank you so much!  I was too careless. This really helps.

Comment: @JustCallMeGary  Perhaps you loaded `plyr` too that masks the `summarise`.  You could explicitly use `%>% dplyr::summarise(new = sum(..`.  In the `group_by`, it should be `group_by(bond)` and not `group_by(local$bond)` (if you check my syntax) i.e. the column name and not the column values

Comment: `weighted.mean(x = b, w = c)`